# why can int not be deferenced?

Tags: java

[image]I'm writing a while loop program and this problem keeps staying here and I'm not sure how to fix it. Keeps displaying "int cannot be dereferenced". I have done a ton of research on this problem and I don't know what am I doing wrong: read on google, read on StackOverflow and so on, but I don't know what to do. Tried the parsing technique but kept saying "scanner cannot convert string to int" Here is my code, any help would be appreciated. I could have declared the variable in the if and else if conditions, but I would like to keep track of what I am doing and I believe it's better to not repeat codes. (such as print out statement)

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner Data = new Scanner (System.in);
   final int goldplated = 100, fourteen = 500, eighteen = 1000;
   int total = 0, count = 1, size = 0;
   String GetInfo = "";
   System.out.println("How many times do you want to purchase:");
   int EnterData = Data.nextInt();
   
   
   while(count<=EnterData){
       System.out.println("What Kind of Chain do you want to buy? Below are the list of options: \n 1 - gold plated \n 2 - 14k gold \n 3 - 18k gold");
       //GetInfo = Data.next();
       if (Data.equals("1")||Data.equals("gold plated")){
           System.out.println("Please specify the length of the chain.");
           size.nextInt();
           total = size * goldplated; 
       }else if(Data.equals("2")||Data.equals("14k gold")){
           System.out.println("Please specify the length of the chain.");
           size.nextInt();
           total = size * fourteen;
       }else if(Data.equals("3")||Data.equals("18k gold")){
           System.out.println("Please specify the length of the chain.");
           size.nextInt();
           total = size * eighteen;
       }else{
           System.out.println("Invalid operation");
       }    count++;
            total+= size.nextInt();
            System.out.println("This is your price: " + total);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you keep testing to see if your `Data` variable is equal to different strings? It's a `Scanner`, not a string... never going to be equal.

Comment: I believe that was a mistake and I forgot to make changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this out for me, as soon as I entered a number it kept crashing. Sorry, I'm a starter so I make quite silly mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

`nextInt()` is a method in the `Scanner` class.  So when you write `something.nextInt()`, the `something` part will have to be a `Scanner` object.  And in your case, you've got a `Scanner` object, which you've called `Data` (not the best name for it, but never mind).

If you write `Data.nextInt()`, your program will wait for the user to type in a number, and return that number.  That's what you want, but you'll want a variable to assign that number to, so that you can use it.  That variable is `size`.  So every time you've written `size.nextInt();` in your program, what you actually need to write instead is `size = Data.nextInt();` - that is, call the method on the `Data` object, and assign the result to the `size` variable.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. There was another comment prior to yours, I guess it got deleted where it told me to create a different class and so forth.

Comment: Yes, Elliott deleted their answer.  I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe it's because my comments were inappropriate or too childish, I wanted to rebuild my homework by following what he said yesterday but unfortunately, he deleted his comments already. Either way, your solution worked really well, once again, thank you. This isn't the final program yet, I still have more things to add.